# urllib2.URLError from python script

Tags: python

I am running a python script that checks a text file on my server and then turns on a relay dependent on what it reads. If it turns on the relay after a time delay the script sends a GET request to update the text file on the server to then turn the relay off. 
The program runs all ok for some time. I can turn on and off the relay ans it updates the server when the time delay has time out.
If i leave the program running and  do nothing after some time i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "remote-relay.py", line 41, in <module>
  readWeb ()
File "remote-relay.py", line 34, in readWeb
  relaystatus = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

this is the python script

```
import urllib2
import wiringpi2
import time

url = "http://www.stevesolarhome.com/WaterControl.txt"
url2 = "http://www.stevesolarhome.com/water/water.php?status=0"
wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.pinMode(17,1)
wiringpi2.pinMode(27,1)
wiringpi2.pinMode(22,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(27,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(22,1)
def requestOFF ():
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url2).read(1)
def delay ():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 400:
        counter += 1 
        time.sleep(2)
            relaystatus = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(1)
            if relaystatus == "0":
            waterOFF ()
            counter = 400
        time.sleep(2)
    requestOFF ()
    time.sleep(3)
def waterOn ():
    wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,0)
    delay ()        
def waterOFF ():
    wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)
def readWeb ():
    relaystatus = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(1)
    if relaystatus == "1":
        waterOn ()
    elif relaystatus == "0":
        waterOFF ()
    time.sleep(2)
while 1:
    readWeb ()
```

It cant be a URL no found as the URL exists and the program runs all ok at the beginning.

Is the script wrong, or is it requesting data to often

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your internet connection or DNS resolution randomly dies.

The "Name or service not known" error happens when for some reason, the URL cannot be resolved via DNS.

Comment: is there a way to resend the request if this happens and stop the python program crashing

Comment: Yes, you can "catch" (using an "except" block) the URLError to handle it. Look here for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Thanks for the link i will have a read of this tonight and see if i can get this to work